# Why is total harmonic distortion defined in the following manner?

Tags: voltage, power, audio, frequency, harmonics

So the total harmonic distortion is defined as

$$THD = \sqrt{\frac{V_{2}^2 + V_{3}^2 + V_{4}^2...+V_{n}^2}{V_{1}^2}}$$

which means Total harmonic distortion is defined as the square root of the ratio of the average power delivered by harmonic components divide power delivered by non-harmonic component. So why include the square root when it would make more intuitive sense not to include it in the first place?

Comment: *when it would make more intuitive sense not to include it* That might be so in **your** intuition but in mine it does not. The **sum of squares** makes more sense to me as it is the way that uncorrelated signals need to be summed up.

Comment: The root sum of squares term is added because when the terms are negative and others are positive it would not make sense to have these terms cancel out when they both contribute to the signals distortion.

Comment: Apologies I have edited the formula

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Without the squareroot the definition of the equation becomes total power delivered by harmonic components/total power delivered by fundamental frequency. Which begs the question, why take the squareroot when this is a valid measure of harmonic distortion?

Comment: I wonder what the difference is between RMS of Fourier spectrum of harmonics and ratio of asymmetry error in time domain  |V-p + V+p|/Vavg *100% for a sine

Comment: it doesn't happen when each is squared

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie I agree with Tony, this doesn't happen as the values are squared.

Comment: My bad, I was confusing the squares and square-root. The square root is needed to "compensate" for squaring the \$V_n\$ terms. Suppose \$V_2\$ doubles, then without the squareroot, the THD would be cubed (\$V_2^2\$) which isn't true, THD should only have doubled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the voltages are in rms. Remember that the rms voltage is the equivalent DC voltage source that delivers the same amount of power to a resistive load. The rms is given by

$$v_\mathrm{rms} = \sqrt{\frac{1}{T} \int_{0}^{T} v^2 \ \mathrm{d}t}.$$

In our case \$v\$ is a sum of pure sine waves. Hence it is easier to work in the frequency domain, if you do not have a burning desire of evaluating integrals containing products of sine waves.

The rms in the frequency domain is given by

$$V_\mathrm{rms} = \sqrt{\frac{1}{N^2} \sum_{i = 1}^N |V_i |^2},$$

where \$V_i\$ are the frequency components and \$N\$ is the number of samples. Now remember that a sine wave satisfies

$$|V| = \frac{A}{2} (\delta(f - f_0) + \delta(f + f_0)).$$

Hence a single harmonic has two components with amplitude \$A / 2\$. Thus

$$V_\mathrm{rms}^2 = \frac{1}{N^2} \frac{A^2}{2}.$$

Consider what happens when we take the rms of a waveform comprising two distinct harmonics with amplitudes \$A_1\$ and \$A_2\$. Then you have

$$V^2_\mathrm{rms} = \frac{1}{N^2} \left( \frac{A_1^2}{2} + \frac{A_2^2}{2} \right).$$

Substituting the rms of the first harmonic \$V_1\$ and the rms of the second harmonic \$V_2\$ yields

$$V_\mathrm{rms} = \sqrt{V_1^2 + V_2^2}.$$